# Received CA callback for state, but active state queue is empty

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I get a crash of UIPageViewController:Received CA callback for state, but active state queue is empty.

Comment: Please provide relevant code in your project

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: I'm fully understand author, I have the same crash, only thing which I know - if remove UIPageViewController from project - everything works fine. And no way to reproduce.. Random crash from users once a week

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was because of user turning pages too fast, so I had to slow down the user like this:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    
    pageViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

and then in

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute: {
        pageViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    })
}
```

you can also ignore asynAfter if you feel sure the viewController is fast.